# Using diffForHumans with strototime

Tags: laravel, php-carbon

I am trying to use diffForHumans with a date that is in string format.  I used strtotime to convert the string to Unix Timestamp.  The problem is now I am getting an error that cannot covert integer to time.  What am I missing?

Here is my code.

```
<td>{{strtotime($user['scan'])->diffForHumans(time())}}</td>
```

$user['scan'] is a date that is a string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use parse. The date is compared to the current time by default.

```
<td>{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($user['scan'])->diffForHumans() }}</td>
```